# SharePoint JSOM display next 6 items on each scroll event

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom

We have a requirement to show 6 items from SharePoint list on scroll event. That is: On each scroll event we need to show the next 6 items in a div section

Has anybody worked on this type of requirement?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. But you can use OOTB list web part. Set item limit to 6 on page. Which will automatically give you the next and previous button to scroll through all items

Comment: we need to show in an html page (customization) on scroll event we need to show 6 item per scroll event.

Comment: What do you mean by scroll? Horizontal or vertical? You can fetch all items from list using REST and use bootstrap carousel type functionality to show the items on html page

Comment: vertical scroll on a html page , on each scroll event we have load next set of  6 items from a list, bootstrap carousel does not serve the purpose.. i believe.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you will be able to achieve this..Below code snippet will help you understand.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getFirstSixItems, "sp.js");

    $('#idOfYourItemContainer').scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            if (nextPagingInfoBday) {
                position = new SP.ListItemCollectionPosition();
                position.set_pagingInfo(nextPagingInfoBday);
            }
            else {
                position = null;
            }

            getNextData();
        }
    });

});


function getFirstSixItems() {
    Context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);
    objWeb = Context.get_web();
    objList = objWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("YourListName");
    camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query><RowLimit>6</RowLimit></View>');
    itemCollection = objList.getItems(camlQuery);
    Context.load(itemCollection);
    Context.load(objWeb);
    Context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailOfLoad));
}

function onSuccess() {

    listItemEnumerator = itemCollection.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        //html operation to diplay items in your container
    }

    if (itemCollection.get_listItemCollectionPosition()) {
        nextPagingInfoBday = itemCollection.get_listItemCollectionPosition().get_pagingInfo();
    } else {
        nextPagingInfoBday = null;
    }
}

function onFailOfLoad(sender, args) {
    alert(' failed');
}


function getNextData() {
    if (position != null) {
        //If more items are to be fetched, make a second call to the server and fetch the next group of items.
        camlQuery.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position);

        itemCollection = objList.getItems(camlQuery);
        Context.load(itemCollection);

        //Call the same function recursively until all the items in the current criteria are fetched.
        Context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailOfLoad));
    }
}
```